# scala store method in set with possibility of removal

Tags: scala, set

Here's some test code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

object Test extends App
{
    val set: Set[Int => Boolean] = new HashSet()

    def test(i: Int): Boolean = {
        false
    }

    Console.println(set.add(test)) // true
    Console.println(set.remove(test)) // false
    Console.println(set.add(test _)) // true
    Console.println(set.remove(test _)) // false
}
```

What options are there for making this work?

Edit: I also want this to support lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you perform "add" or "remove" operation Scala compiler creates new  AbstractFunction1.mcZI.sp object instance:

```
 Console..MODULE$.println(BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean(set().add(
    new AbstractFunction1.mcZI.sp() { 
    public final boolean apply(int i) { return apply$mcZI$sp(i); } 
    public boolean apply$mcZI$sp(int i) { return Test..MODULE$.test(i); }
 })));
```

As I understand this object instance doesn't contain information about enclosing object and 'test' method which can be used for 'hashCode' and 'equals' methods.
I think as a workaround you may consider this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

object Test extends App
{
    val set: Set[Int => Boolean] = new HashSet()

    def test(i: Int): Boolean = {
        false
    }

    val testFunc: Function1[Int, Boolean] = test
    Console.println(set.add(testFunc)) // true
    Console.println(set.remove(testFunc)) // true

    val testPartFunc = test _
    Console.println(set.add(testPartFunc)) // true
    Console.println(set.remove(testPartFunc)) // true
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't `Console.println(set.remove(test _))` work? It's the same, except you store it in a variable.

Comment: No. If you decompile your class you will see that compiler creates 'new AbstractFunction1.mcZI.sp()' four times. So, actually you operate with 4 different objects of the same type.

Comment: Well, that behavior is ridiculous. Basically, it means I have to store all method > function conversions in variables right next to the methods themselves, and the more methods I need to store, the more pointless code bloat it creates...

Comment: I don't understand why `test _` does not return some constant function object. The decompiled code in the picture shows that there is no difference at all between passing `test` or `test _`, which doesnt make sense. Is that actually my code that's decompiled in that picture?

Comment: There is no difference between passing `test` or passing `test _`. The only reason you can write `test` as an argument to the `add` and `remove` methods is because the compiler can infer that you want to treat it as a partially applied function.

Comment: @jurchiks `test _` cannot return a constant function object because it needs to not only encapsulate the method `test`, but also the `this` pointer at that point in the code. In this case it may be inside an `object`, but there are very good reasons why the code is made to behave the same as if it were in a `class`.

Comment: @serg.f.ya You might want be interested in scalac's `-Xprint` options (e.g. `-Xprint:all`). They output the AST at points in the compilation, giving similar information to a decompiler, but often more easily understood.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing... Guess I'll just have to create the private variables in cases where unregistering is needed.

Answer (score -1):

If instead of passing methods you pass function it works:

```
val testFun: Int => Boolean = i => i > 10
set.add(testFun) // true
set.remove(testFun) // true
```

it will also work for anonymous functions:

```
set.add { _ => false }
```

but then I don't know how you would like to remove such function from the set.

Comment: The thing is that `test _` supposedly converts the method to a function, but it still doesn't work.